# Turan's proof of Hardy-Ramanujan theorem: Estimation of $\sum_{n = 1}^{N} V(n)^2$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

In the [proof of the Hardy–Ramanujan theorem by Paul Turan](https://archive.org/details/on-a-theorem-of-hardy-and-ramanujan/mode/1up), at the end of the proof, it is stated that

> If, instead of (4), we use the more precise but also elementary relation
> $$\sum_{p_i \leq M} \frac{1}{p_i} = \log \log M + a + o(1) $$
> where $a$ is a constant, we obtain in the same way the results
> $$R(N) = N \log \log N + o(N \log \log N)$$

I tried to follow the proof but I can't get to the desired conclusion.

In the proof of Lemma 4, it uses that
$$\left( \sum_{p_i \leq \sqrt{N}} \frac{1}{p_i} \right)^2 < \sum_{p_i p_h < N} \frac{1}{p_i p_h} < \left( \sum_{p_i \leq N} \frac{1}{p_i} \right)^2$$

If I use the [Merten's Second Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensSecondTheorem.html),
$$\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p} = \log \log x + B_1 + o(1)$$
where $B_1$ is the [Mertens constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensConstant.html), I get:

\begin{align*}
        \left( \sum_{p_i \leq N} \frac{1}{p_i} \right)^2 & = \left( \log \log N + B_1 + o(1) \right)^2 \\
        & = \left( \log\log N \right)^2 + 2 B_1 \log \log N + B_1^2 + o(\log \log N) \\
        & = \left( \log\log N \right)^2 + 2 B_1 \log \log N + o(\log \log N)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
        \left( \sum_{p \leq \sqrt N} \frac{1}{p} \right)^2 & = \left( \log\log \sqrt N \right)^2 + 2 B_1 \log \log \sqrt N + o(\log \log \sqrt N) \\
        & = \left( \log\log N - \log 2 \right)^2 + 2 B_1 \left( \log\log N - \log 2 \right) + o(\log\log N - \log 2) \\
        & = \left( \log \log N \right)^2 - 2 \log 2 \left( \log \log N \right) + 2B_1 \log \log N + o(\log \log N) \\
        & = \left( \log \log N \right)^2 + (2 B_1 - 2\log 2) \log \log N + o(\log \log N)
\end{align*}

Using this, I can only say that there exists a constant $c$ such that:
$$\sum_{p_i p_h \leq N} \frac{1}{p_i p_h} = \left( \log \log N \right)^2 + \left( 2B_1 - c \right) \log \log N + o(\log \log N)$$
where $0 < c < 2 \log 2$.

Then, following the proof, we can get

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{N} V(N)^2 = N(\log \log N)^2 + (2 B_1 - c + 1) N \log \log N + o(N \log \log N)$$

Also, we use the following result:
$$\sum_{n \leq x} V(n) = x \log \log x + B_1 x + o(x)$$

Lastly,

\begin{align*}
R(N) & = \sum_{n = 1}^N (V(N) - \log \log N)^2 \\
& = \sum_{n = 1}^N V(n)^2 - 2 \log \log N \sum_{n = 1}^{N} V(n) + N(\log \log N)^2 \\
& = N(\log \log N)^2 + (2 B_1 - c + 1) N \log \log N + o(N \log \log N) - 2 \log \log N \left( N \log \log N + B_1 N + o(1) \right) + N(\log \log N)^2 \\
& = (-c + 1) N \log \log N + o(N \log \log N) \\
\end{align*}

It seems like that I can do something better to eliminate the $c$, but I am not aware of a way to do so. Could you give me some suggestions?

Comment: i'm not sure, but from a quick glance it seems you're not inserting the given relation in the equation involving $\sum V(n)^2$ at the end of page 275, which i think you need to do

Comment: (and i don't think you need to look at lemma 4)

Comment: I hope this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568855/on-the-second-moment-of-prime-divisor-function/4569423#4569423) addresses your concern.