# On the second moment of prime divisor function

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Let $\omega(n)$ denote the number of distinct prime divisors of $n$. I learned from Cojocaru & Murty that

$$
\sum_{n\le x}\omega(n)^2=x(\log\log x)^2+O(x\log\log x).\tag1
$$

I wonder whether it is possible to extract more terms from the O-error. This will be crucial because (1) only implies

$$
\sum_{n\le x}(\omega(n)-\log\log x)^2=O(x\log\log x).\tag2
$$

If (1)’s second term can be extracted, then (2) will become an asymptotic formula instead of some error bound.

In my attempt, the main difficulty lies in the treatments for

$$S=\sum_{p_1p_2\le x}{1\over p_1p_2}$$

If we only roughly estimate $S$ via

$$
\left(\sum_{p\le\sqrt x}\frac1p\right)^2\le S\le\left(\sum_{p\le x}\frac1p\right)^2,
$$

then we only end up with (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By graphing a hyperbola, one finds that

$$
\sum_{p_1p_2\le x}{1\over p_1p_2}=\left(\sum_{p\le x}\frac1p\right)^2-\sum_{p_1\le\sqrt x}{1\over p_1}\sum_{x/p_1<p_2\le x}{1\over p_2}-\left(\sum_{\sqrt x<p\le x}\frac1p\right)^2.
$$

The last two terms are bounded, and the first square term is asymptotic to

$$
(\log\log x)^2+2B_1\log\log x+o(1).
$$

due to Mertens' theorem. As a consequence, we have

$$
\sum_{n\le x}\omega^2(n)=\sum_{p_1\ne p_2}\left\lfloor x\over p_1p_2\right\rfloor+\sum_{p\le x}\left\lfloor\frac xp\right\rfloor=x(\log\log x)^2+(2B_1+1)x\log\log x+O(x).
$$